# Can't animate a position change of two container UIViews that have child view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have two views in self.view that are **container views** (via storyboard: each has an embed segue in viewDidLoad which loads up their respective child view controller). They're called self.leftPane and self.rightPane. I'm using auto-layout.

I want to animate a position change of self.leftPane, as it moves from x=0 to x=(negative something). I'm basically trying to make a hamburger menu on the left, in a simple fashion...

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftPane: UIView! // has child view controller embedded
@IBOutlet weak var rightPane: UIView! // has child view controller embedded

        // in/after viewDidAppear
        self.leftPaneLeftConstraint.constant = 0 - self.leftPane.frame.size.width + 20.0

        UIView.transition(with: self.leftPane, duration: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.leftPane.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finished) in
            self.leftPaneIsFull = false
        })
```

The problem is that there's no animation -- it just jumps. **I've tried UIView.transition with different views, and different UIView.animate flavors**, all with the same effect (no actual animation).

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use UIView.animate instead of UIView.transition.I wrote down the code sample.Are you try this code?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var leftPane: UIView! // has child view controller 
  embedded
 @IBOutlet weak var rightPane: UIView! // has child view controller embedded

   // in/after viewDidAppear
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

        self.leftPaneLeftConstraint.constant = 0 - self.leftPane.frame.size.width + 20.0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { (success) -> Void in

           //You can write something you want

           })
        }
    })
```

**Enjoy it :)**

Comment: I figured it out before you answered, the issue wasn't the transition (as I mentioned, i had tried UIView.animate as well). The issue was that the layoutIfNeeded() wasn't being called high-enough up the view hierarchy, ie. needed to do `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: I have been happy for you solved problem.Thanks for rep. @xaphod